# Alexa skill development with team collaboration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

We have a small team that needs to collaborate on a single Alexa skill. However, an Interaction Model exists under only a single user account. No one else has access to edit the Model. Has anyone solved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional users to your Alexa account.

Using the default role of `developer` the user would have the ability to manage the model, but lack the ability to view any payment/financial based configuration.

Generally you would open the Alexa account for the Organisation you represent and add each developer to the account afterwards.

Follow the instructions [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/app-submission/manage-account-and-permissions.html#add_other_users) for adding a user and assigning them permissions.